# How can I test the content of a file uploaded to an FTP?

Tags: java, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I'm trying to receive a file uploaded to a (citrus) ftp server and verify that the content of the file uploaded is as expected.

I've managed to receive the `STOR` message (my code below), but I don't know how can I test that content is equals to some text (I'm working with xml, json and csv files).

Can you help me?
Thanks.

```
@Test
public class SampleFtpTest extends TestNGCitrusTestDesigner {
    @Autowired
    private FtpServer ftpServer;

    @CitrusTest
    public void testFileContent() {
        Condition waitUntilFileIsUploaded = new Condition() {
            @Override
            public String getName () {
                return "Check files on FTP";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSatisfied (TestContext testContext){
                return new File("target/ftp/user/anonymous").listFiles().length != 0;
            }

            @Override
            public String getSuccessMessage (TestContext testContext){
                return "Files found in FTP!";
            }

            @Override
            public String getErrorMessage (TestContext testContext){
                return "No file was found in FTP";
            }
        };

        waitFor().condition(waitUntilFileIsUploaded).seconds(1200L).interval(5000L);

        // simulate integration uploading a file...
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20000L);
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -T /tmp/test.txt ftp://localhost:22222 --user anonymous:secret");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        // don't care about connection related messages
        receive(ftpServer);
        receive(ftpServer);
        receive(ftpServer);
        receive(ftpServer);
        receive(ftpServer);

        // i'd like to assert that the uploaded files content is as expected
        receive(ftpServer).header("citrus_ftp_command", FTPCmd.STOR.getCommand());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is _"assert about the file content"_?  And BTW, there is no way to know deterministically when an FTP file transfer is "complete".  All you can do is guess based on lack of activity, and even that will fail in some situations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I din't know that there is no way to know deterministically when an FTP file transfer is "complete". 
Also, I've edited the question in order to clarify what I was trying to do.

Comment: Yes, that is an unfortunate "feature" of FTP.  A transfer can fail, leaving a partial file, and then be restarted or resumed.  If you need determinism you should switch to something like rsync, which can be configured to write to a hidden temporary and rename it to the target file only when complete.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to test the file content adding a `ChannelEndpoint` which reads the file from the ftp working directory. Then I can test the file content doing this:

```
receive(fileEndpoint)
            .header("file_originalFile", "@contains('/test.txt')@")
            .payload(new ClassPathResource("ar/com/jidev/citrus/samples/expected/test.txt"));
```

For more information I uploaded the full example [here](https://github.com/jdetomasi/citrus-ftp-sample)